# Varying SQL Query Result in Ruby On Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a function:

```
    def self.run_all_scheduled_reports
            scheduled_queries = Reports.find(
                :all,
                :joins=> 'INNER JOIN `expected_times` 
                 ON (`reports`.`report_id` =`expected_times`.`report_id`)')

            if scheduled_queries.empty?
                print "No reports to run at this time ("+Time.now.to_s+")"
            else
                caught_exception = false
                ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET SESSION WAIT_TIMEOUT=2400");
                scheduled_queries.each do |query|
                    begin
                        print "Running report ("+query[:id].to_s+")...\n"
                        self.run_report(query[:id])
                    rescue Exception => e
                        caught_exception = true
                        print e
                    end
                end
                raise "At least one query resulted in an Exception!" if caught_exception
            end
        end
```

The weird thing is that, when i run this function consecutively (via script/runner -e ...), the result varies. Sometimes about 30 reports are printed while sometimes just 15 (and sometimes, no results at all are returned). You guys have any idea whats happening? My DB is MYSQL.

Also, if i change the environment to "development" OR if i omit the JOIN part, its working pretty well.

Comment: Is anything else changing the database? Have you tried your queries in the MySQL shell?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in debugger mode?  I've seen cases where an exception gets eaten in the rails stack silently in some weird cases.

Comment: @muistooshort - The database itself lives in a server so most likely there are reads and writes, but I am the only one accessing the tables used above.  Yes, ive tried feeding MYSQL raw queries - results are good.

Comment: I just solved the issue, the inconsistency happens because apparently, rails is set to use another layer to do the db transactions. This middle layer randomly reads from 2 seperate MYSQL boxes, which turned out to be out of sync. Once i synced the 2 boxes, the problem was fixed. Thanks for all the help

Comment: It's best to write an answer to your own question and accept it for others to find it.  (It'll also pull this question out of the unanswered list.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the issue, the inconsistency happens because apparently, my rails is set to use a separate layer/framework to do the db transactions. This middle layer randomly reads from 2 seperate MYSQL boxes, which turned out to be out of sync. Once i synced the 2 boxes, the problem was fixed. Thanks for all the help